Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank when fitting model
I am trying to train a deep audio classification model. When checking the shapes of the testing and training data it is (16, 6245, 257, 1), 16 being the number of items in the batch, 6245 being the width, 257 being the height, and 1 being the channel. I then accordingly created this input layer in my neural network:
model.add(Input(shape=(6245, 257, 1)))

and I am able to create the model and even get a model summary. But when I go to train the model with:
hist = model.fit(train, epochs=6, validation_data=test)

I get this error:
Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.

I am using tensorflow 2.17 in a jupyter notebook in an anaconda environment.
Note: I am converting my audio to spectogram and the mapping this function onto the whole dataset.
def preprocess(file_path, label): 
    def load_and_preprocess(path):
        wav = load_wav_16k_mono(path)
        wav = wav[:200134]
        zero_padding = tf.zeros([200134] - tf.shape(wav), dtype=tf.float32)
        wav = tf.concat([zero_padding, wav], 0)
        spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(wav, frame_length=320, frame_step=32)
        spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)
        spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, axis=-1)
        return spectrogram

    # Use tf.py_function to wrap the file loading and preprocessing
    file_path = tf.convert_to_tensor(file_path, dtype=tf.string)
    spectrogram = load_and_preprocess(path)
    
    return spectrogram, label

Nevertheless, checking the shape of the spectrogram also returns TensorShape([6245, 257]) so it is the same as the sample being passed into the model.
How do I solve this issue?
